# Bundling 2 .exe's together in a C# application

Tags: c#, exe, process.start

I want to write an application that launches another app using Process.Start , but that app is a .exe, can I bundle that into my C# app without it being outside in a folder? I want to make it so my app doesn't need to install at all, so can it be in the app?

Comment: Is the other exe written in .Net?

Comment: You can add the exe to your resources and when needed you can extract it to a temporary forlder and use it from there along with Process.Start().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely sure if I understand, but do you mean so you can ship it and send it around as a single .exe (rather than zipping it all up)?

Could you embed the .exe in as an [embedded resource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) and have your own .exe put it in some temporary files?

Comment: Alright, that seems like the best way to go. How could I put it in a temporary diretory Home/AppData/Local/Temp

Comment: There are many different places you could put it. If you want the local temp files though, I'd suggest using environment variables to get the paths. The locations would be different on different versions of Windows.

Comment: But how can I access it, and move it. In C#

Comment: Use the `File` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx). Now, for anything else, please do some research yourself or ask it in a separate question. Sorry! :P

Answer (score 0):

You want to make two exe's look like one exe?

There is no reasonable way to do this.  Are you using someone else's program and don't want people to know?

Comment: Just put the exe in as a binary resource, then extract and run it. That's pretty reasonable to me. I think this isn't without precedent either: a lot of people do it with assemblies (.dll) to ease deployment.

Comment: no, you see I don't want to have to install. I want it to be able to run the .exe without copying it